# What does 90th, 95th & 99th pct matrices means in dashboard report of jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In jmeter 3.0 I have created dashboard report but getting problem in reading some matrices like 90th, 95th and 99th pct in statistics. What these actually means?

Comment: here is a book I own where you can brush up on your statistical working knowledge.  You will need it for performance testing, https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Dummies-Lifestyle-Deborah-Rumsey/dp/1119293529

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The 90th percentile is the value for which 90% of the data points are smaller

The 90th percentile is a measure of statistical distribution, not unlike the median. The median is the middle value. The median is the value for which 50% of the values were bigger, and 50% smaller. The 90th percentile tells you the value for which 90% of the data points are smaller and 10% are bigger.

Statistically, to calculate the 90th percentile value:
1. Sort the transaction instances by their value.
2. Remove the top 10% instances.
3. The highest value left is the 90th percentile.

Example:
There are ten instances of transaction "t1" with the values 1,3,2,4,5,20,7,8,9,6 (in sec).
1. Sort by value — 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,20.
2. Remove top 10 % — remove the value "20."
3. The highest value left is the 90th percentile — 9 is the 90th percentile value.

The 90th percentile value answers the question, "What percentage of my transactions have a response time less than or equal to the 90th percentile value?" Given the above information, here is how LoadRunner calculates the 90th percentile.[enter link description here](https://softwaretesttips.com/2011/04/11/what-is-the-90th-percentile-and-how-is-it-calculated/)

Comment: it is copy-paste from here: [What is the 90th percentile and how is it calculated](https://softwaretesttips.com/2011/04/11/what-is-the-90th-percentile-and-how-is-it-calculated/)

Comment: @catch23 Subramaniyan Well the page is dead , so it is useful that the answer is actually here :) Could you update your link here as well?

Comment: @Batselot here is the wayback link
https://web.archive.org/web/20160314084246/http://softwaretesttips.com:80/2011/04/11/what-is-the-90th-percentile-and-how-is-it-calculated/